# Dynamically updating index.html file in production build of a create react app

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, server-side-rendering

My client app is built with Create React App, which comes which lots of conveniences built-in. However it's not possible to do server side rendering out of the box. As a result, once the `build` command is run, all of the output is effectively static.

I have a use case where I do NOT want to switch to complete SSR setup, but would like to dynamically add some data to `index.html` file so that it is immediately available in javascript when client first loads file.

I worked out the following solution:

- React app runs as a docker container, using the `serve` lib to serve static build content
- A separate node service runs in a different docker container and has access to the build content from the react app via a shared volume
- The node service runs a function every few minutes that reads the contents of `index.html` file using `fs`, inserts some additional data into a script tag (e.g. `window.myData={someKey: 'someValue'}`), and writes the updated string to `index.html`.

Locally using `docker-compose`, this works great. However, I'm wondering about possible ramifications of this approach, especially cases where an incoming request for the react app will fail because of some kind of file lock on `index.html` as it's being read / written by the node service.

I don't *think* this would be an issue, but I had enough doubt to post this question. The last thing I can afford are failed requests in my production app because of some unforeseen issue.

Any advice, suggestions, anecdotes, etc. are appreciated!

Comment: I know quite some time passed, but still: did you manage to solve this, without resorting to docker etc.? Maybe in a way similar to @Phuoc Do's answer?

Answer (score 1):

I've successfully added SSR for CRA without ejecting. If that's your only use case, the SSR setup will be super simple as you don't have to deal with webpack or babel configs. If you are interested, follow 3 steps below:

- Step 1: Add a basic Express server in a new folder at your root/ project folder (same level as src/)
- Step 2: For main app routes, read file build/index.html and edit it as you want before sending.
- Step 3: Other than those routes, serve CRA build/ static files as suggested by CRA SSR documentation

**TL;DR**

```
// root/server/index.js (your build is at root/build)
const express = require("express");
const fs = require("fs");
const path = require("path");

const app = express();

// step 2
const renderContent = (req, res) => {
  fs.readFile(
    path.resolve(__dirname, "../build/index.html"), "utf8", (err, htmlData) => {
      if (err) {
        return res.sendStatus(500);
      }

      /* Do something with htmlData here */

      return res.send(htmlData);
    });
}

app.use("^/$", renderContent); // step 2
app.use(express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, "../build"))); // step 3
app.use("*", renderContent); // step 2

// step 1
app.listen(process.env.PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Listening on port ${process.env.PORT}`);
});
```

Then, you just need to run: `node server/index.js`, and this server will serve your Create React App normally, except for the part that you edit your HTML above.

Comment: Thanks for response. I also did this a few months back and I believe it mostly worked, but I recall that using typescript presented some challenges where I needed separate `tsconfig.json` files for server and client. Also I believe using built-in CRA live reload for local development presented some challenges. Do you run this setup locally and if so have you run into any issues?

Comment: To use the same file tsconfig.json for the server-side, change the rootDir option to project folder root/ instead of folder root/src. With this tweak, root/server folder will also be included in the tsconfig.json. To use the built-in CRA development server, change step 3 as below: `if (NODE_ENV === "development") { const proxy = createProxyMiddleware({ target: "http://localhost:3000", changeOrigin: true }); app.use(Express.static("public")); app.use(/^\/(static|asset-manifest.json).*/, proxy); } else { app.use(Express.static("build")); } `

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will help, but as a suggestion. I faced a similar usecase. I solved it very simply using [HtmlWebpackPlugin](https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin).

Inside the  webpack configuration. I write something like:

```
 new htmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: path.join(rootpath, '', 'index.html'),
      inject: false //<-- Notice here
    })
```

I set the "inject" to false and using this flag it does not append the script's/bundle on index.html and at the same time it allowed us to use ejs templating to loop over the file's we want to append on index.html.

Like on index.html I wrote:

```
 <% for (var chunk in htmlWebpackPlugin.files.chunks) { %>
                <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<%= htmlWebpackPlugin.files.chunks[chunk].css %>">
                <script src="<%= htmlWebpackPlugin.files.chunks[chunk].entry %>"></script>
                <% } %>
```

My suggestion would be create a separate chunk/file(js) of that data you want to append dynamically on index.html and using [EJS](https://ejs.co/#docs) templating, you can achieve the desired result.

How to Create Chunks: *[READ HERE](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/split-chunks-plugin/)*

Thanks, Hope it Help.

Comment: You do this with a creat-react-app application? Where is your webpack configuration?